# How to find debugs symbol in *.so files by ctypes in python?

Tags: python, ctypes

I write a code that, search for so library and load it by ctypes.CDLL in to python. How to find debugs symbol in *.so librarys, and avoid to load 
when find "undefined symbol:" error ?

Comment: What use do you have for *debug* symbols in your program? If you need to debug, attach gdb to the process.

Comment: I have to detect and skip loading library with error "undefine symbols" and continue loading library without this OSError.  Code, will be run os independent, and I have to use only lib in *.so extension. The code is make for proof of concept and is part of large idea.

Comment: Problem, solve by this solution [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799974/continue-on-except-of-a-try-block-in-python)